# CQ Workflow, purpose of "Handler Advance"?

Tags: aem

I am working with some custom WorkflowProcess classes in Adobe CQ 5.4

When I configure the workflow step as part of my workflow model, there is an checkbox entitled "Handler Advance, Check if your handler will advance to the next step"

My Java classes do in fact progress the workflow (and sometimes terminate the workflow).
i.e.

```
workflowSession.complete(workItem, routes.get(0));
workflowSession.terminateWorkflow(workItem.getWorkflow());
```

Given that this custom WorkflowProcess performs these operations, I think that I should be checking the "Handler Advance" option.

I was hoping for a better explanation on this option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The handler advance option when **true** (checked), will advance the workflow to the next step after the current process is done with its execution.

In case the handler advance option is **false** (unchecked), the process script has to take care of advancing the workflow to the next step. In case the script doesn't handle this, the workflow would remain in the running state without proceeding further from the current step.

Since your custom workflow process progresses the workflow to the next step, it doesn't make any difference having the handler advanced option checked or unchecked.