# CQ5.6 - Not completing workflow stuck in "stale" state

Tags: workflow, aem

I've created a very basic process step from the example adobe gives on their website. http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/workflows/wf-extending/dev-steps.html#par_title_0b
However for the life of me I can't get this to work. I'm not getting any errors and if I try to log something in my class nothing is getting logged. It's as if it's not even hitting this class. All I have in my example workflow is:

Flow Start -> {Process Step} -> Flow End

Also, for whatever reason it's as if my workflow isn't getting completed. Whenever I try to complete a workflow it says **This page is subject to workflow:**. My page is just ending up **Stale** and it seems like it never completes the workflow. Any ideas on what's going on and why it seems to not complete the workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your process step in the Workflow editor has *Handler Advance* option checked:

> Select this option to automatically advance the workflow to the next step after execution. If no selected, the implementation script must handle workflow advancement.
>   [source](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/workflows/wf-ref.html)

Also, you may advance the workflow manually using the Java API - check out this question to see a [sample code excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923417/cq-workflow-purpose-of-handler-advance).

Comment: thanks for replying. The handler advance option is checked and the arguments are set to true. What I think is going on is that I'm installing a ton of files and I believe in the process many of the workflows are moving to the STALE state and blocking further processing. I'm not sure if there's a way around this. To my understanding anytime you install a package with lots of assets it will fire a DAM Update Asset workflow. Any ideas on ways around this? There's also an adobe thread with the same problem that never got solved: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1262426?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: If you see them in STALE that should mean that some process failed in the background, but you can only find it out from the logs or if you are debugging the code. FIrst, check the logs, also check whether the user has the necessary permissions for writing the workflow instances.