# Need help in programmatically advance to next step in CQ 5.5 workflow process step

Tags: aem

Below is the code I am using to programmatically move to next workflow step i.e. auto handler advance programmatically instead of selecting the checkbox auto handler advance on the step.

```
List<Route> routes = workflowSession.getRoutes(workItem);
            if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(routes)) {
                for (Route route : routes) {
                    logger.info("Route: " + route.getName() + " route: " + route);
                }
                workflowSession.complete(workItem, routes.get(0));
            }
```

Although the  logger gives me the right route information I am not able to proceed to the next step and the workflow goes on running state.

References used for the above code:

[API Reference](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/workflows/wf-extending.html#Managing%20Work%20Items)

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923417/cq-workflow-purpose-of-handler-advance)

Kindly let me know what am I missing.
Let me know if you need more details and will update the question.

Comment: Just checked my custom WF Step and I do it exactly the same way. So the question is, could it be that the next step in the chain is blocked?

Comment: Is there anything disturbing in your logs?